# NullPointer with Reactive Spring Elastic Repository mocked into a service

Tags: spring, kotlin, elasticsearch, mockito

This is the snippet of my test class:

```
 

    @SpringBootTest
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
    class ResourceSearchServiceTest {
        @Mock
        lateinit var resourceSearchRepository: ResourceSearchRepository
    
        @InjectMocks
        lateinit var resourceSearchService: ResourceSearchService
    
        lateinit var expectedResourceMetadata : ResourceSearchMetadata
    
        @BeforeEach
        fun createResourceMetadata() {
            expectedResourceMetadata =
                ResourceSearchMetadata(
                    id = UUID.randomUUID(),
                    pk = UUID.randomUUID(),
                    metadata = ResourceMetadata(
                        description = "blabla"
                    )
                )
        }
    
        @Test
        fun activeResourceMetadataTest() {
            Mockito.`when`(resourceSearchRepository.findById(any(UUID::class.java))).thenReturn(Mono.just(expectedResourceMetadata))
            Mockito.`when`(resourceSearchRepository.save(any(ResourceSearchMetadata::class.java))).thenReturn(Mono.just(expectedResourceMetadata))
            resourceSearchService.updateActiveStatus(expectedResourceMetadata.id,  false)
            Mockito.verify(resourceSearchRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(expectedResourceMetadata)
            assertThat(expectedResourceMetadata.metadata.active).isFalse
        }
    }
```

and this is my service :

```
    @Service
    class ResourceSearchService(private val resourceSearchRepository: ResourceSearchRepository) {
         fun updateActiveStatus(id: UUID, isActive: Boolean) {
             resourceSearchRepository.findById(id).flatMap { resource ->
                 resource.metadata.active = isActive
                 resourceSearchRepository.save(resource)
             }.map { Success }.defaultIfEmpty(NotFound)
         }
    }
```

when updateAciveStatus service method is called from the test class a nullpointer exception is raised by the repository at this line :

```
 resourceSearchRepository.findById(id)
```

It's like the mocked repository is not injected into the service.

Any idea what's wrong in my Kotlin code ?

Comment: For starters your `@SpringBootTest` doesn't add anything here (only a delay in your test as the app is started and then discarded in your test). Instead of `@INjectMocks` try to create an instance of your service in the `@BeforeEach` and inject the mocked repository. See if that works.

Comment: It's not working! mock is not invoked error